# I want to make a parameterized function in javascript in which on button

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic, parameters, append

I want to make a parameterized function in javascript
in which on button click an HTML <label> tag should be append with unique id every time I click on button with a parameter value.

Comment: So, what's your problem?

Comment: Could you please describe your problem? This way we cant help. We are not here to build software for eachother, just to help eachother out with specific problems.

Comment: i don't know how to write it , as i m on beginning level . Can you please help me write the syntax?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: how do you want the button to hold a "parameter"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you are trying to bind a click event to a `<label>` tag. So just find it on the dom

```
var myLabel = document.getElementById('--your label id--');
```

And then call

```
myLabel.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // your code goes here
    console.log('hey there!');
});
```

If you happen to be using jQuery, you can use a cleanner syntax:

```
$('#label').on('click', function () {
    // you can even fetch data from the label:
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    var customData = $(this).data('customData');
    /* ... */
});
```